# How can I smooth this face?

Tags: geometry

I have a face that does not follow suit I have tried everything I can come up with but for some reason this face does not have the same shading as the others.

Any help here would be great cause it is like a bad headache and rater be rid of it.

I already have edge split and tried to extrude the face from the previous one that does have correct shading.[image: bad face shading with wrong normal vector]

Comment: did you check the normals ? maybe this face has an inverse normal compared to others ....

Comment: It's not easy to see the problem with only this screenshot. Please consider uploading your blend file.

Answer (score 1):

I want to give credit to this post the answer to put the f2 add on was a bit weird but simply deleting the face only and removing doubles and after selecting the vertices and fill helped and is the solution for me.

[Smooth shading is seemingly creating incorrect normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46001/smooth-shading-is-seemingly-creating-incorrect-normals)
[image]